# How do I center these nav icons vertically in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-navbar

I am wondering how to center these icons vertically within their button. I want them to be centered vertically regardless of what device they are displayed on. Thanks!

```css
#footer {

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#footerbuttons {
 height: 3vh;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Mobile</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--jQuery CDN Hosted Files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- PAGE 1 ---------------------------->
 <div data-role="page" id="school1">


  <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <div data-role="navbar">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#" id="footerbuttons" data-icon="mail" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="footerbuttons" data-icon="camera" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" id="footerbuttons" data-icon="heart" data-iconpos="notext" data-role="button"></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you icons are `:after` element using position:absolute

Comment: Your markup isn't correct. Refer to this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navbar/

Comment: Please avoid that `id="footerbuttons"`- instead use a `class`. Id's shall be unique inside a page.